# Remove ASP.NET MVC6 Server header

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

The HTTP response from an ASP.NET MVC6 application has a header `Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0`

I want to remove/change this header. I have tried adding a Filter which replaces the header

```
public class RemoveServerHeaderFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Set("Server", "Replaced");
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

I get the unexpected and unwanted result of `Server: Replaced Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0`

Is there anyway to replace this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this header is not coming from the framework but from IIS, [this article shows 3 different techniques to remove it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/varunm/archive/2013/04/23/remove-unwanted-http-response-headers.aspx)